# Изменить ImageView из ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Добрый день. Я создал `ListView` с кастомизированным Adapter'ом.

```
public class SurahAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<Surah> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    Surah data[] = null;


    public SurahAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Surah[]data){
        super(context,layoutResourceId, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ArtistHolder holder = null;
        View row = convertView;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ArtistHolder();
            holder.suraTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.suraTitle);
            holder.verseCount = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.verseCount);
            holder.place = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.place);
            holder.surahBG = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.surahBG);


            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ArtistHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Surah surah = data[position];
        holder.suraTitle.setText("Сура " + surah.suraTitle);
        holder.verseCount.setText(surah.verseCount);
        holder.place.setText(surah.place);
        holder.surahBG.setImageResource(surah.surahBG);

        return row;
    }

    static class ArtistHolder
    {
        TextView suraTitle;
        TextView verseCount;
        TextView place;
        ImageView surahBG;
    }

}
```

В `MainActivity` присваиваю `ListView` свой `Adapter`

```
SurahAdapter adapter = new SurahAdapter(this,
            R.layout.surah_lv_layout, surah);
    suraLV.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на элемент списка, он менял картинку из `ImageView surahBG` на иконку воспроизведения звуковой дорожки. Подскажите как это организовать?

Answer (score 1):

Заведите в данных признак `boolean isPlaying` и в зависимости от него устанавливайте картинку. Если кроме смены картинки предполагается использование другого layout'а для элемента списка (например progress еще добавите или время до конца трэка), то лучше реализовать через `getViewTypeCount/getItemViewType`.

По нажатию меняйте данные, вызывайте `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Comment: Так я и спрашиваю, как правильно эту картинку поменять?))

Comment: В `getView` заполнение данных должно выглядеть примерно так `if (surah.isPlaying){ holder.surahBG.setImageResource(surah.surahBG);} else {holder.surahBG.setImageResource(surah.surahBG2);}`

Answer (score 0):

В обработчике `OnClick` клади в этот самый `surahBG` новое изображение и вызывай 
`((BaseAdapter) suraLV.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Сделал как ты говоришь, при скролле картинка обратно меняется на ту, которая там была до этого.

Comment: Дело в том, что адаптер _удаляет_ `holder` когда, тот выходит за пределы экрана. Не буду тут рассказывать как это работает, информации полно. Чуть ниже тебе вроде дали понять, что надо тогда   отличать 2 изображения...